# Problem with user reputation and/or missing questions

Tags: support, migration, users

I was just looking at the users list (specifically rep in the last month) and then looked at a couple of user profiles. These users have 500+ rep even though it says they have 0 questions and 0 answers:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/9607/alan-h
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/10172/rook

They do have several badges that imply they have asked or answered questions. I'm assuming a bug with question display?

Answer (score 3):

Both users' reputation appears to be related to a deleted question which was migrated from StackOverflow - here's the original: [How do Google+ +1 widgets break out of their iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313037/how-do-google-1-widgets-break-out-of-their-iframe?noredirect=1)

Comment: Yeah, that question was migrated here and then migrated back. Whatever rep was associated with that question stayed here (and I think also carried over to StackOverflow).

Comment: Aha! Was wondering about this...

Comment: So how come the question was migrated back? Nothing here suggests it would be: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/554/annoyed-my-question-was-migrated-from-so

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and deleted those accounts to clean up.

(They can always recreate them, but neither user seemed particularly interested in this site, which is perhaps another argument in favor of the un-migration of that question..)